# _pickle.UnpicklingError: pickle data was truncated line 27 Server.py

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, pickle, python-3.8

```
_pickle.UnpicklingError: pickle data was truncated line 27 Server.py
```

**I'm trying to build a screen sharing app with python**

I get this error: `_pickle.UnpicklingError: pickle data was truncated in`  **<-- Server.py line 27**

It works in the same computer

But when I run server and client in different pc's then it won't work

Please help me out

Server.py

```
# CONSTANTS
BUFFER = 1024 * 8
ADDR = '192.168.20.4'
PORT = 9090

# Create Server
server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server.bind((ADDR, PORT))
server.listen(1)

# Display Image
def display(client):
    while True:
        # Get Data
        client.send(b's')
        dataBin = b''
        while True:
            dataBin_ = client.recv(BUFFER)
            dataBin += dataBin_
            if len(dataBin_) < BUFFER: break

        # Display Screen
        screen = pickle.loads(dataBin)

        cv2.imshow('Screen', screen) # <-- here is the problem
 
        cv2.waitKey(1)

# Accept Connections
client, address = server.accept()
print(f'{address[0]} is connected!')

print(client.recv(10))
display(client)
```

Client.py

```
import socket, pickle, time, cv2
import pyautogui
import numpy as np

# Constants
BUFFER = 1024 * 8
ADDR = '192.168.20.4'
PORT = 9090

# Connect to Server
client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
client.connect((ADDR, PORT))

# Cool down time
time.sleep(2)

# Stream Screen
while True:
    screen = np.array(pyautogui.screenshot())
    screenGray = cv2.cvtColor(screen, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    lowResGrayImg = cv2.resize(screenGray, (1280,800), fx=0, fy=0, interpolation=cv2.INTER_CUBIC)

    if client.recv(1) == b's':
        client.send(pickle.dumps(lowResGrayImg))
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/homepro/PycharmProject/Projects/Socket/Virus/LiveScreenStream/server.py", line 38, in <module> display(client)
  
File "/Users/homepro/PycharmProject/Projects/Socket/Virus/LiveScreenStream/server.py", line 27, in display screen = pickle.loads(dataBin)

_pickle.UnpicklingError: pickle data was truncated
```

Comment: Actually, I misread that `recv` loop. The problem is that you terminate reading when `client.recv` reads less than the full buffer. What you ought to do is first send the size of the pickled data (in bytes) and then follow that by the pickled data. That way the server will first read the size, and then keep receiving until it got exactly that amount.

Comment: the loop adds the last piece of data (which is less than `BUFFER`) to `dataBin` before breaking the loop. So I should get all the data right? Can `len(data)` be less than `BUFFER` and then in the next loop be more than `BUFFER`?